# Setting up Visual Studio Intellisense for CUDA kernel calls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, intellisense, gpu

I've just started CUDA programming and it's going quite nicely, my GPUs are recognized and everything. I've partially set up Intellisense in Visual Studio using this extremely helpful guide here: 
[`http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/`](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/)

and here:
[`http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/`](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/)

However, Intellisense still doesn't pick up on kernel calls like this:

```
// KernelCall.cu
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void kernel(void){}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The line kernel<<<1,1>>>() is underlined in red, specifically the one arrow to the left of the first one with the error reading "Error: expected and expression". However, if I hover over the function, its return type and parameters are displayed properly. It still compiles just fine, I'm just wondering how to get rid of this little annoyance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Visual Studio provides IntelliSense for C++, the trick from the rocket scientist's blog is basically relying on the similarity CUDA-C has to C++, nothing more.

In the C++ language, the proper parsing of angle brackets is troublesome. You've got `<` as less than and for templates, and `<<` as shift, remember not long ago when we had to put a space in between nested template declarations.

So it turns out that the guy at NVIDIA who came up with this syntax was not a language expert, and happened to choose the worst possible delimiter, then tripled it, well, you're going to have trouble. It's amazing that Intellisense works at all when it sees this.

The only way I know to get full IntelliSense in CUDA is to switch from the Runtime API to the Driver API. The C++ is just C++, and the CUDA is still (sort of) C++, there is no `<<<>>>` badness for the language parsing to have to work around.

Comment: I must say, you make more sense than anyone on the NVIDIA forums... So how do I go about doing what you just said?

Comment: Take a look at the difference between matrixMul and matrixMulDrv.  The <<<>>> syntax is handled by the compiler essentially just spitting out code that calls the Driver API calls.  You'll link to cuda.lib not cudart.lib, and may have to deal with a "mixed mode" program if you use CUDA-RT only libraries.

Comment: See my reply to your question on my blog. Spider is correct. It's unlikely that this will ever work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I mostly wanted to know if this was expected behavior and this essentially puts my mind at ease. Thanks again.

Comment: Update: 2021. Visual Studio 2019 does fairly well if you #include "cuda_runtime.h" and add the CUDA includes to your include path. On my machine it comes out to be
  C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include

Comment: Update 2021: Also #include <device_launch_parameters.h> does even more.

Comment: @Richard-Keene what do you mean by "does fairly well in 2021? There still is the red underline for the kernel call and the "expected an expression" error message in Vistual Studio 2019

Comment: Yes, still the red underline problem, and <<< and >>> get turned into << <   >> > by formatting.

Answer (score 42):

Wow, lots of dust on this thread. I came up with a macro fix (well, more like workaround...) for this that I thought I would share:

```
// nvcc does not seem to like variadic macros, so we have to define
// one for each kernel parameter list:
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define KERNEL_ARGS2(grid, block) <<< grid, block >>>
#define KERNEL_ARGS3(grid, block, sh_mem) <<< grid, block, sh_mem >>>
#define KERNEL_ARGS4(grid, block, sh_mem, stream) <<< grid, block, sh_mem, stream >>>
#else
#define KERNEL_ARGS2(grid, block)
#define KERNEL_ARGS3(grid, block, sh_mem)
#define KERNEL_ARGS4(grid, block, sh_mem, stream)
#endif

// Now launch your kernel using the appropriate macro:
kernel KERNEL_ARGS2(dim3(nBlockCount), dim3(nThreadCount)) (param1);
```

I prefer this method because for some reason I always lose the '<<<' in my code, but the macro gets some help via syntax coloring :).

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. In addition, not "#end" but "#endif" is right. sorry for tiny little things.

Comment: It seems that `__INTELLISENSE__` is safer choice than `__CUDACC__` check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182137/8037585  and https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/513485/cuda-programming-and-performance/__syncthreads-is-undefined-need-a-help/

Comment: This is a helpful solution but extremely ugly. Hopefully Microsoft modifies Intellisense so that solutions like this one are no longer necessary

Answer (score 11):

From VS 2015 and CUDA 7 onwards you can add these two includes before any others, provided your files have the `.cu` extension:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
```

No need for MACROS or anything. Afterwards everything will work perfectly.

Comment: Select in your error list "build only" to get rid of the "expected an expression" errors

Comment: Works for me on VS 2019. My only question: is `#include "cuda_runtime.h"` needed? My simple test looks fine with just `#include "device_launch_parameters.h"`.

Comment: Errors? You mean red lines? Can you give an example?

Comment: Adding these lines doesn't seem to work for me either, on VS2019 Community. @BartDeBoeck That just filters the error list, not the highlighting.

Comment: Yeah this does not fix Intellisense issues for me in VS2017

Answer (score 4):

I LOVED [Randy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4463172/randy)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061565/setting-up-visual-studio-intellisense-for-cuda-kernel-calls/27992604#27992604). I'll match and raise using C preprocessor variadic macros:

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
#define CUDA_KERNEL(...)
#else
#define CUDA_KERNEL(...) <<< __VA_ARGS__ >>>
#endif
```

Usage examples:

```
my_kernel1 CUDA_KERNEL(NUM_BLOCKS, BLOCK_WIDTH)();
my_kernel2 CUDA_KERNEL(NUM_BLOCKS, BLOCK_WIDTH, SHMEM, STREAM)(param1, param2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've been learning CUDA and have encountered that exact issue. As others have said, it's just Intellisense problem and can be ignored, but I've found a clean solution which actually removes it.

It seems that <<< >>> is interpreted as a correct code if it's inside a template function.

I've discovered it accidentally when I wanted to create wrappers for kernels to be able to call them from a regular cpp code. It's both a nice abstraction and removes the syntax error.

kernel header file (eg. kernel.cuh)

```
const size_t THREADS_IN_BLOCK = 1024;

typedef double numeric_t;

// sample kernel function headers
__global__ void sumKernel(numeric_t* out, numeric_t* f, numeric_t* blockSum, size_t N);
__global__ void expKernel(numeric_t* out, numeric_t* in, size_t N);
// ..

// strong-typed wrapper for a kernel with 4 arguments
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void runKernel(void (*fun)(T1, T2, T3, T4), int Blocks, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4) { 
    fun <<<Blocks, THREADS_IN_BLOCK >>> (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}

// strong-typed wrapper for a kernel with 3 arguments
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void runKernel(void (*fun)(T1, T2, T3), int Blocks, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) { 
    fun <<<Blocks, THREADS_IN_BLOCK >>> (arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

// ...

// the one-argument fun cannot have implementation here
void runKernel(void (*fun)(), int Blocks);
```

in a .cu file (you will get a syntax error here, but do u ever need a parameter-less kernel function? if not, this and a respective header can be deleted):

```
void runKernel(void (*fun)(), int Blocks) { 
    fun <<<Blocks, THREADS_IN_BLOCK >>> ();
}
```

usage in a .cpp file:

```
runKernel(kernelFunctionName, arg1, arg2, arg3);
// for example runKernel(expKernel, B, output, input, size);
```