# How do I set up CUDA v4.0 to work nicely with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, cuda, syntax-highlighting

I would like to set VS 2010 up so that it knows where the include directory is for all CUDA libraries (including CUTIL) and also preferably to get syntax highlighting. I don't really care about code complete as much, but that would be nice too.

Most important is that I want to be able to create a blank CUDA project, put my code in there, compile and run it.

All the search results I come across are for older versions of either VS or CUDA.

Comment: For syntax highlighting, see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180555/how-to-get-vs-2010-to-recognize-certain-cuda-functions?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Windows search doesn't find any devenv.exe, and putting the usertype.dat in the folder mentioned has no effect.

Comment: If you don't have devenv.exe, you don't have Visual Studio. Look harder in your Program Files (x86) directory.

Comment: It's VS 2010 Express, there's no devenv.exe in my Program Files; Program Files (x86) or any other directory. This key is also non-existant in my registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppPaths\devenv.exe