# <<< >>> cuda in vscode

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-code

Are there any way to suppress "<<< >>>" error with vscode-cpptools.

I associate "*.cu" with "cpp" in `setting.json`.

```
// use normal c++ syntax highlighting for CUDA files
  "files.associations": {"*.cu": "cpp"},
```

and work fine except of one problem,  `kernel execution configuration parameters surrounded by <<< and >>>` mistaked as error `expected an expression`

```
dim3 dimGrid(2, 2, 1);
dim3 dimBlock(width / 2, width / 2, 1);
MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_M, d_N, d_P, width);
```

Any suggestion

Comment: You can try this extension:- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kriegalex.vscode-cudacpp

Comment: @sonulohani I dit try this extension but it just give some code snippt and can NOT autocomplete cuda function like `cudaMalloc` `cudaMemcpy` that ms-vscode.cpptools can if I include `cuda_runtime.h` and `device_launch_parameters.h`

Answer (score 10):

googling for a few hours, find no perfect solution but some workaround.

I summarize here:

- use normal c++ syntax highlighting for CUDA files by editting`setting.json`
- include necessary header of CUDA in program
- include dummy header to workaround INTELLISENSE

Bellow is a concrete example

- setting.json

> ```
> "files.associations": {
>     "*.cu": "cpp",
>     "*.cuh": "cpp"
>   }
> ```

- cudaDmy.cuh

> ```
> #pragma once
> #ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
> void __syncthreads();  // workaround __syncthreads warning
> #define KERNEL_ARG2(grid, block)
> #define KERNEL_ARG3(grid, block, sh_mem)
> #define KERNEL_ARG4(grid, block, sh_mem, stream)
> #else
> #define KERNEL_ARG2(grid, block) <<< grid, block >>>
> #define KERNEL_ARG3(grid, block, sh_mem) <<< grid, block, sh_mem >>>
> #define KERNEL_ARG4(grid, block, sh_mem, stream) <<< grid, block, sh_mem,    
> stream >>>
> #endif
> ```

- matrixMul.cu

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <math.h>
> #include <time.h>
> #include <cuda.h>
> #include "cuda_runtime.h"
> #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
> #include <device_functions.h>
> #include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
> #include "cudaDmy.cuh"
>
> __global__ void MatrixMulKernel(float *M, float *N, float *P, int width)
> {
>     int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
>     int Col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
>     if (Row < width && Col < width)
>     {
>         float Pvalue = 0;
>         for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
>         {
>             Pvalue += M[Row * width + i] * N[width * i + Col];
>         }
>         P[Row * width + Col] = Pvalue;
>     }
> }
>
> void MatMul(float *M, float *N, float *P, int width)
> {
>     float *d_M;
>     float *d_N;
>     float *d_P;
>     int size = width * width * sizeof(float);
>     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_M, size);
>     cudaMemcpy(d_M, M, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
>
>     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_N, size);
>     cudaMemcpy(d_N, N, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
>
>     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_P, size);
>
>     dim3 dimGrid(2, 2, 1);
>     dim3 dimBlock(width / 2, width / 2, 1);
>     // <<<>>> will replace macro KERNEL_ARG2 when compiling 
>     MatrixMulKernel KERNEL_ARG2(dimGrid,dimBlock) (d_M, d_M, d_P, width);
>     cudaMemcpy(P, d_P, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
>     cudaFree(d_M);
>     cudaFree(d_N);
>     cudaFree(d_P);
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     int elem = 100;
>     float *M = new float[elem];
>     float *N = new float[elem];
>     float *P = new float[elem];
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < elem; ++i)
>         M[i] = i;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < elem; ++i)
>         N[i] = i + elem;
>
>     time_t t1 = time(NULL);
>     MatMul(M, N, P, sqrt(elem));
>     time_t t2 = time(NULL);
>     double seconds = difftime(t2,t1);
>     printf ("%.3f seconds total time\n", seconds);
>     for (int i = 0; i < elem/1000000; ++i)
>         printf("%.1f\t", P[i]);
>     printf("\n");
>     delete[] M;
>     delete[] N;
>     delete[] P;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Let's compile it with NVCC

```
nvcc matrixMul.cu -Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=unrecognized_pragma" -o runcuda
```

***useful links:***

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/513485/cuda-programming-and-performance/__syncthreads-is-undefined-need-a-help/post/5189004/#5189004
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182137/8037585
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992604/8037585
- https://gist.github.com/ruofeidu/df95ba27dfc6b77121b27fd4a6483426

Answer (score 1):

You can just download the [vscode-cudacpp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kriegalex.vscode-cudacpp) extention and than in your workspace(<>.workspace) or user settings(.vscode/settings.json) enable this option:

```
"settings": {
    "files.associations": {
        "*.cu": "cuda",
        "*.cuh": "cuda"
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that (at least for me) this will enable syntax highlighting but not intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

As sonulohani pointed out the cuda-cpp extension. It is good and it is the only extension available for CUDA. if you want autocomplete then try the CUDA-C++ package in sublime text editor. That provides excellent autocomplete features.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official extension by NVIDIA named [Nsight Visual Studio Code Edition](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nsight-vscode-edition)

You could try and install it in your vscode.