# CUDA 5 and Visual Studio 2010 intellisense error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have installed CUDA 5 toolkit (32 and 64 bit as that seemed to work) and have made a CUDA runtime project in VS 2010, it compiles fine and runs but I get a red line under the call to the CUDA function.

It isn't a massive deal but it is a little annoying, is there any way to remove this? I'm guessing it is some project setting or some such but I have no idea and neither does Google.

I have attached a screenshot so you know what I am talking about.

Thanks for reading this, I appreciate it.

Kevin

[image]

Comment: In the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page, search on `cuda red underline` and you'll get a number of hits with suggestions.

Comment: @RobertCrovella 4 hits, no answer for one, one not relevant. One possibly relevant. The last is relevant and this duplicates it almost exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061565/setting-up-vs-2010-intellisense-for-cuda-kernel-calls

Comment: CUDA runtime <<<>>> syntax is not compliant with the C++ language causing C++ compliant tools (even ones with relaxed requirements) to show it as an error.

Comment: The triple-chevron syntax is problematic, since it's already overloaded in so many contexts in C++; that could be some combination of less than signs, bit shifts, template brackets, or pipping (how cout, etc use it). Don't have too high of expectations for intellisense.

Comment: We have same question.
and, Any update on this?

[this is my question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954102/errors-that-occur-when-i-start-the-kernel-function-in-cuda-5-5

Comment: We have same question.
and, Any update on this?

[this is my question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954102/errors-that-occur-when-i-start-the-kernel-function-in-cuda-5-5

Comment: We have same question.
and, Any update on this?

[this is my question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954102/errors-that-occur-when-i-start-the-kernel-function-in-cuda-5-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a combination of the answers above (thank you) I have the answer to this question just in case anyone else stumbles upon it.

Basically this is not a compile error, or even an error at all. It is a problem with intellisense and from what I can see, nothing can be done about it, just have to live with it, or hope that one day they add a little more support.

The <<< >>> is the problem and is not correct C++ syntax according to intellisense which favours the C++ compiler. However that code it compiled by the CUDA compiler which intellisense couldn't give a damn about.

I could probably go into more depth about it but read the above comments and search this site as suggested and you will understand.