# Errors that occur when I start the kernel function in CUDA 5.5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, cuda, windows-7-x64

I installed CUDA5.5.
Development environment is using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
And I tried to run the source code like the following.
However, the red line was drawn to the part of "<<<" for some reason on Visual Studio.
It is displayed Error "expression. Required" and.
If anyone the same phenomenon is happening, please tell me how to solve.

Development environment--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
         OS:Windows7 64bit
         Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1
         CUDA 5.5
```

Phenomenon-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

↓Underlined red part of the "<<<" of source code you'll see the following.
However, the third underline appears only "<".
It appears to be: "expression Required. Error" and move the mouse pointer to the location of the red line.

Source code---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <cuda.h> 

#define N 256


__global__ void matrix_vector_multi_gpu_1_1(float *A_d, float *B_d, float *C_d){
    int i,j;

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        A_d[j]=0.0F;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            A_d[j]=A_d[j]+B_d[j*N+i]*C_d[i];
        }
    }
  }

int main(){
    int i,j;
    float A[N], B[N*N], C[N];
    float *A_d, *B_d, *C_d;

    dim3 blocks(1,1,1);
    dim3 threads(1,1,1);

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            B[j*N+i]=((float)j)/256.0;
        }
    }

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        C[j]=1.0F;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&A_d, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&B_d, N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&C_d, N*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(A_d,A,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(B_d,B,N*N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(C_d,C,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    matrix_vector_multi_gpu_1_1<<<blocks,threads>>>(A_d,B_d,C_d);

    cudaMemcpy(A,A_d,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("A[ %d ]=%f \n",j,A[j]);
    }
    getchar();
    cudaFree(A_d);
    cudaFree(B_d);
    cudaFree(C_d);
    return 0;
}
```

[The place of occurrence](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/qRdmQdtNzDBhZyCp0nSuVbyMRkeCzJRvHqXCOIA5dn4=w725-h207-p-no)

Comment: bad link 'The place of occurrence'

Comment: Now, I tryed compiling and running "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5\0_Simple\simplePrintf". and succeeded. but, Visual Studio Editor show same red line "Error : expression. Required" .  I do not understand what's going on?

Comment: Perhaps it is only an Intellisense problem. You may wish trying to add Intellisense support for CUDA. Have a look at [Visual Studio 2010 Adding Intellisense Support for CUDA C](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least change from

```
cudaMemcpy(A,A_d,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

to

```
cudaMemcpy(A,A_d,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

A few more suggestions

- Run some CUDA sample code to see if you have setup CUDA correctly.
- Make sure your source code file have the external name `.cu`

After solving the `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` issue, I can compile and run your code. And the result is corrected. You code should have no problem that prevent compiling.

Comment: But, Now Problem is still there. Underlined red part of the "<<<" of source code. I think this is only editor's occur, isn't it?

Comment: Have you ever succeed compiling and running other `.cu` files like CUDA sample codes in your environment?

Comment: I have ever succeed compiling and running "nbody". There is C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5\5_Simulations\nbody             and It use the "<<<" in the same way as when  use a function called "integrateBodies" in there but a red underline is not drawn.

Comment: Try to ignore that and directly compile it to see if there's any problem.

Comment: The red underline is due to the fact that intellisense (part of visual studio IDE) is not recognizing the CUDA syntax.  The red underline *by itself* does not necessarily indicate a problem in a CUDA code.  If your code compiles and runs correctly, the red underline can safely be ignored.  If you want more information about it or ideas for how to eliminate/work around it, put "cuda red underline" in the search box in the upper right hand corner of this page, and search on it.  You will find many questions reporting the same, and some ideas about how to "fix" it.

Comment: The presence or absence of the red underline may be affected by which header files are included which may be a difference between the nbody sample and your code.

Comment: Thank you Robert.  well, the source code at this page that I wrote is not nbody's source code.   it is my sample code( A = B * C ). and when I conpiled nbody,　I just compiled file as you have installed.about the include file in my sample code, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in my comment above, this is an Intellisense problem. The steps to enable Intellisense support on a Visual Studio 2010 CUDA project are summarized at

[Setting Intellisense support for a Visual Studio 2010 CUDA project](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/536)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, JackOLantern. but, There was no change that I tried. and, I see the usertype.dat, and I noticed that "<<<" is not located at the file(usertype.dat). What display of "<<<" in the environment of everyone it going?

Comment: I think you will not be able to avoid the wavy red line under the last  `<` of the CUDA delimiter `<<<`. As long as I know, adding the delimiters `<<<` and `>>>` is the only actual extension CUDA is making out of C/C++, so I think Intellisense, which has been on the contrary designed for C/C++, will never recognize the `<<< >>>` syntax in Visual Studio 2010.