# How to eliminate the intellisense warning under the <<<>>> in vs2019

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, c++17, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I'm trying my first cuda example with vs2019,but i don't know how to eliminate the warning under the <<<>>>, it looks dirty

```
add <<<1, 1 >> > (2, 7, dev_c);
```

[image]

Comment: What does the warning/hint say?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't

Comment: As an aside: When copy-pasting in VS, you can prevent/undo the spaces within <<< and >>> with CTRL-V, CTRL-Z

Answer (score 1):

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want so far.**

C++ does not support such cuda's style of writing so far by default. And VS only partly inherits CUDA functionality.

After all, * is not a cuda-specific language editor, so it can't get full Intellisence. It is also only a partial inheritance.

As a suggestion from [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061565/setting-up-visual-studio-intellisense-for-cuda-kernel-calls), you should

> switch from the Runtime API to the Driver API. The C++ is just C++,
> and the CUDA is still (sort of) C++, there is no <<<>>> badness for
> the language parsing to have to work around.

Besides, if it does not meet your requirement, you should contact with the Team to [suggest a feature about idea](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8).

Comment: Could you implement C++-compliant operators <<, <, >>, > that swallow the operator symbols and the parameters inside the paranthesis for Intellisense only? Or won't it work, because they are binary?

Comment: Maybe you should [extend language service for c++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-editor-and-language-services?view=vs-2019). For vs, you should create a your own extension.