# Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense not working for CUDA (.cu Files)

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2017, gpu, intellisense

I cannot get Intellisense to work on any of my .cu files (CUDA files). I tried the methods discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6061565/7852589) and [here](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/) and so now I am wondering if anyone can help me solve this issue.

So far, I have added .cu to the known extensions list and `$(CUDA_INC_PATH)` to the list of included directories, but still all .cu files look like this:

[image]

CUDA files compile and run fine of course, but its just Intellisense that does not work on .cu files. Intellisense seems to be fine with extensions of other languages.

- Visual Studio Professional 2017
- CUDA v10.2

Comment: Note that this question may be more well suited on https://superuser.com. Does this solve your issue: https://superuser.com/questions/58318 ?

Comment: Seems like the answer to that question is now a broken link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could not really find what the issue was and ended up updating my Visual Studio to VS2019 Professional with CUDA 11.2 and only then the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

My environment:

**CUDA 11.2 Update 2**

**Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.9.31**

[image]

It works well in my side. Make sure that your VS2017 has installed C++ workload.

So please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any other third party extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates**-->**Installed**

**2)** close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**Then**, restart VS to test again.

**Further**, you could rename the whole `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx` folder to another name like `vs2017`(which is more like a delete operation and the new `vs2017` folder is a backup ) or just delete the folder and then re-login into VS.

**3)** [repair VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or just update it to the latest version.

**4)** install the latest **CUDA 11.2** version and then try the **step 2** to test again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did all the steps but they didn't fix the issue. I ended up uninstalling VS2017 and installing VS2019 instead and that fixed the issue.